# Thread waiting to multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, synchronization

I have to create a hedge simulator. There is eg. 10 segments of it and each of them should have its own dedicated Thread simulating grow of the segment (each time we're about to calculate whether segment growed up, we should perform random test).
In addition there should be one additional, gardener Thread.
Gardener should cut segment of hence, when its size reaches 10 (then he cuts its size back to initial level of 1 and adds notifies it in his notes).

My attempt to make it working was like this:

```
public class Segment implements Runnable {
    private int currentSize;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(Math.random() < 0.3)
            incrementSize();
    }

    private synchronized void incrementSize() {
        currentSize++;
    }

    public synchronized int getCurrentSize() {
        return currentSize;
    }

    public synchronized void setCurrentSize(int newSize) {
        currentSize = newSize;
    }
}

public class Gardener implements Runnable {
    private int[] segmentsCutAmount = new int[10]; //Gardener notes
    private Collection<Segment> segments;

    public Gardener(Collection<Segment> segmentsToLookAfter) {
        segments = segmentsToLookAfter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            //Have no idea how to deal with 10 different segments here
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    private Collection<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<>():
    public void main(String[] args) {
        Main program = new Main();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            program.addSegment();

        Thread gardenerThread = new Thread(new Gardener(program.segments));
    }

    private void addSegment(Collection<Segment> segments) {
        Segment segment = new Segment();
        Thread segmentThread = new Thread(segment);
        segmentThread.start();
        segments.add(segment);
    }
}
```

I am not sure what am I supposed to do, when segment reaches max height.
If there was 10 gardeners, every of them could observe one segment, but, unfortunelly, gardener is a lonely shooter - he has no family and his friends are very busy and are not willing to help him. And are you willing to help me? :D
I generally know basics of synchronization - synchronized methods/blocks, Locks, wait and notify methods, but this time I have totally no idea what to do :(
Its like horrible deadlock! Of course I am not expecting to be spoonfeeded. Any kind of hint would be very helpful as well. Thank you in advance and have a wonderful day!

Comment: You could create a `BlockingQueue` in which hedges insert themselves once they grow above height 8, and which the gardener takes his work orders from. But you'll have to add code for a better answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. "My attempt to make it working was like this" could you post [mcve] to demonstrate it ?

Comment: Hey daniu, thank you for your answer. Even if I added segments to the queue, wouldn't the gardener still be able to observe grow of only one at the time? I will be very grateful for the code to clarify.
c0der thank you! I tried to present my problem simpliest as possible.
I didn't attach any code, because I have only random test working, and I don't have any idea how to solve the rest of task. I need rather a more general help at the time.

Comment: No, any segment thread that will rich let's say height 8 will put in the blocking queue 'something for gardener', when there will be elements in the queue, the gardener will unblock and will read off the queue and process/cut the segment, when the queue will be empty, the gardener will block again and wait for the segments to grow

Comment: For "more general help" this site is not the correct place. Maybe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ would be more appropriate.

Comment: I added minimal, complete and verifable example

Comment: I guess `boolean getCurrentSize()`  should return int

Comment: You guessed correctly, thank you. Corrected.

Comment: @M.leRutte when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Didn't suggest to cross post, but that there is another stackexchange site which I think might be better suited for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

About that queue. You can use the `ExecutorService` for that.

**Letting the Hedge grow**

So let's you have a hedge that can grow and be cut.

```
class Hedge {
    private AtomicInteger height = new AtomicInteger(1);
    public int grow() {
        return height.incrementAndGet();
    }
    public int cut() {
        return height.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

And then you have an environment that will let the hedge grow. This will simulate the hedge sections; each environment is responsible for one of the sections only. It will also notify a `Consumer<Integer>` when the hedge size has gone.

```
class SectionGrower implements Runnable {
    public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private final Hedge hedge;
    private final Consumer<Integer> hedgeSizeListener;
    public SectionGrower (Hedge h, Consumer<Integer> hl) { 
        hedge = h; 
        hedgeSizeListener = hl 
    }
    public void run() {
        while (true) { // grow forever
            try { 
                // growing the hedge takes up to 20 seconds
                Thread.sleep(RANDOM.nextInt(20)*1000);
                int sectionHeight = hedge.grow();
                hedgeSizeListener.accept(sectionHeight);
            } catch (Exception e) {} // do something here
        }
    }
}
```

So at this point, you can do this.

```
ExecutorService growingExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
Consumer<Integer> printer = i -> System.out.printf("hedge section has grown to %d\n", i.intValue());
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Hedge section = new Hedge();
    Environment grower = new SectionGrower(section, printer);
    growingExecutor.submit(grower::run);
}
```

This will grow 10 hedge sections and print the current height for each as they grow.

**Adding the Gardener**

So now you need a Gardener that can cut the hedge.

```
class Gardener {
    public static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    public void cutHedge(Hedge h) {
        try { 
            // cutting the hedge takes up to 10 seconds
            Thread.sleep(RANDOM.nextInt(10)*1000);
            h.cut();
        } catch (Exception e) {} // do something here
    }
}
```

Now you need some construct to give him work; this is where the `BlockingQueue` comes in. We've already made sure the `Environment` can notify a `Consumer<Integer>` after a section has grown, so that's what we can use.

```
ExecutorService growingExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// so this is the queue
ExecutorService gardenerExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadPool();
Gardener gardener = new Gardener();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Hedge section = new Hedge();
    Consumer<Integer> cutSectionIfNeeded = i -> {
        if (i > 8) { // size exceeded?
            // have the gardener cut the section, ie adding item to queue
            gardenerExecutor.submit(() -> gardener.cutHedge(section));
        }
    };
    SectionGrower grower = new SectionGrower(section, cutSectionIfNeeded);
    growingExecutor.submit(grower::run);
}
```

So I haven't actually tried this but it should work with some minor adjustments.

Note that I use the `AtomicInteger` in the hedge because it might grow and get cut "at the same time", because that happens in different threads.

Answer (score 0):

The in following code `Gardner` waits for `Segment` to get to an arbitrary value of 9. 
When `Segment` gets to 9, it notifies `Gardner`, and waits for `Gardner` to finish trimming:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Gardening {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Collection<Segment> segments = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            addSegment(segments);
        }
        Thread gardenerThread = new Thread(new Gardener(segments));
        gardenerThread.start();
    }

    private static void addSegment(Collection<Segment> segments) {
        Segment segment = new Segment();
        Thread segmentThread = new Thread(segment);
        segmentThread.start();
        segments.add(segment);
    }
}

class Gardener implements Runnable {

    private Collection<Segment> segments;
    private boolean isStop = false; //add stop flag

    public Gardener(Collection<Segment> segmentsToLookAfter) {
        segments = segmentsToLookAfter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Segment segment : segments) {
            follow(segment);
        }
    }

    private void follow(Segment segment) {

        new Thread(() -> {

            Thread t = new Thread(segment);
            t.start();
            synchronized (segment) {

                while(! isStop) {
                    try {
                        segment.wait(); //wait for segment
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}

                    System.out.println("Trimming Segment " + segment.getId()+" size: "
                            + segment.getCurrentSize() ); //add size to notes
                    segment.setCurrentSize(0); //trim size
                    segment.notify(); //notify so segment continues
                }
            }

        }).start();
    }
}

class Segment implements Runnable {

    private int currentSize;
    private boolean isStop = false; //add stop flag
    private static int segmentIdCounter = 0;
    private int segmentId = segmentIdCounter++; //add an id to identify thread

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            while ( ! isStop ) {

                if(Math.random() < 0.0000001) {
                    incrementSize();
                }

                if(getCurrentSize() >= 9) {
                    notify(); //notify so trimming starts
                    try {
                        wait(); //wait for gardener to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private synchronized void incrementSize() {
        currentSize++;
        System.out.println("Segment " + getId()+" size: "
                + getCurrentSize() );
    }

    public synchronized int getCurrentSize() {  return currentSize;  }

    public synchronized void setCurrentSize(int newSize) {
        currentSize = newSize;
    }
    public int getId() { return segmentId; }
}
```

The mutual waiting mechanizem can be implemented also with `CountDownLatch`.
 
Note that my experience with threads is limited. I hope other users comment and suggest improvements.